# OpenCTI Iframe - not supported

Tags: iframe, opencti

from my understanding Iframe is not supported since spring 2016. My question is this: im trying to call softphone from salesforce, by creating a call center, and visual force page with the openCTI functionality. but how can I call a third party software if Iframe is not supported in salesforce anymore.

Based on salesforce: 'It functions in conjunction with an iframe offered by salesforce.com to embed 3rd party call control/ softphone applications.'

my code is taken from [link to sample code](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/api_cti.pdf)

Comment: Maybe the link below will help you. Link: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161353/opencti-iframe-not-supported

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the link below will help you:

> ## [Canvas Apps and Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_using_vf_intro.htm)
>
> In addition to standard canvas apps, Force.com Canvas also lets you expose a canvas app on a Visualforce page. This means you can display a canvas app anywhere you can display a Visualforce page.
>
> Developers can use Visualforce pages to:
>
> - Override standard buttons, such as the New button for accounts, or the Save button for contacts
> - Override tab overview pages, such as the Accounts tab home page
> - Define custom tabs
> - Embed components in detail page layouts
> - Create dashboard components or custom help pages
> - Customize, extend, or integrate the sidebars in the Salesforce Console (custom console components)